# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello stack overflow community. i am working on a quiz game and im getting the following error which i think is due to the fact that the textview im trying to create keeps going to null

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
        at com.practechs.kubetnew28_05.GameActivity.addView(GameActivity.java:83)
        at com.practechs.kubetnew28_05.GameActivity.doValidate(GameActivity.java:137)
        at com.practechs.kubetnew28_05.GameActivity.access$200(GameActivity.java:20)
        at com.practechs.kubetnew28_05.GameActivity$1.onClick(GameActivity.java:104)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7441)
```

here is my layout file for the game activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutParent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bgapp"
    tools:context=".GameActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textScreen"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="In Fight Battle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bgquestion"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp">

        <TextView
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/textQuestion"
            android:textColor="#332FA2"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Guess Animals in English language" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="#332FA2"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bgpurple"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:text="Ammo"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the code for the app.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Random;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int presCounter = 0;
    private int maxPresCounter = 4;
    private String[] keys = {"R", "I", "B", "D", "X"};
    private String textAnswer = "BIRD";
    TextView textScreen, textQuestion, textTitle;
    Animation smallbigforth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        smallbigforth = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.smallbigforth);

        keys = shuffleArray(keys);

        for (String key : keys) {
            addView(((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutParent)), key, ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)));
        }

        maxPresCounter = 4;
    }


    private String[] shuffleArray(String[] ar) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            String a = ar[index];
            ar[index] = ar[i];
            ar[i] = a;
        }
        return ar;
    }


    private void addView(LinearLayout viewParent, final String text, final EditText editText) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        linearLayoutParams.rightMargin = 30;

        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);

        textView.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);
        textView.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bgpink));
        textView.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPurple));
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setText(text);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setFocusable(true);
        textView.setTextSize(32);

        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/FredokaOneRegular.ttf");

        textQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textQuestion);
        textScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScreen);
        textTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTitle);

        textQuestion.setTypeface(typeface);
        textScreen.setTypeface(typeface);
        textTitle.setTypeface(typeface);
        editText.setTypeface(typeface);
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(presCounter < maxPresCounter) {
                    if (presCounter == 0)
                        editText.setText("");

                    editText.setText(editText.getText().toString() + text);
                    textView.startAnimation(smallbigforth);
                    textView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(300);
                    presCounter++;

                    if (presCounter == maxPresCounter)
                        doValidate();
                }
            }
        });


        viewParent.addView(textView);


    }


    private void doValidate() {
        presCounter = 0;

        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutParent);

        if(editText.getText().toString().equals(textAnswer)) {
//            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent a = new Intent(GameActivity.this,BossAct.class);
            startActivity(a);

            editText.setText("");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            editText.setText("");
        }

        keys = shuffleArray(keys);
        linearLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (String key : keys) {
            addView(linearLayout, key, editText);
        }

    }


}
```

This issue, i think , is caused by the text view setting to null. ive tried almost all answers ive found on stack overflow. pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the code you provided and found that the `java.lang.NullPointerException` problem you were experiencing probably did not occur when the `GameActivity.java` is opened for first time. That problem pops up when the answer given is wrong.

**Do I understand exactly?**

If so, then the reason is here:

```
private void doValidate (){
....
    linearLayout.removeAllViews ();
....
}
```

In above code, you've removed all child views and then you have called

```
for (String key : keys) {
    addView(linearLayout, key, editText);
}
```

The `editText` you have referenced here, that has also been removed.

So, as expected, `java.lang.NullPointerException` is coming up here:

```
textQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textQuestion);
textScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScreen);
textTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTitle);

textQuestion.setTypeface(typeface);
textScreen.setTypeface(typeface);
textTitle.setTypeface(typeface);
editText.setTypeface(typeface);
```

As `textQuestion`, `textScreen`, `textTitle` and `editText` don't exists anymore.

**What should be done then?**

In fact, the real problem is elsewhere. And that is you have mistakenly named wrong `LinearLayout` as `R.id.layoutParent`. Just add the below line to last `LinearLayout` instead of `root LinearLayout`

```
android:id="@+id/layoutParent"
```

Just like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bgapp"
    tools:context=".GameActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textScreen"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="In Fight Battle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bgquestion"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp">

        <TextView
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/textQuestion"
            android:textColor="#332FA2"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Guess Animals in English language" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="#332FA2"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bgpurple"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:text="Ammo"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutParent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**One more thing that you should take care about.**

Every time you call `addView`, `TypeFace` will be generated from asset and will be assigned to textviews again and again.

You should create class wise variables that can be used later.

Your `GameActivity.java` should be like below:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Random;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int presCounter = 0;
    private int maxPresCounter = 4;
    private String[] keys = {"R", "I", "B", "D", "X"};
    private String textAnswer = "BIRD";
    private TextView textScreen, textQuestion, textTitle;
    private Animation smallbigforth;
        
    // Create variables here

    private Typeface typeface;
    private EditText editText;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Get typeface from asset
        // then assign it to desired views

        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/FredokaOneRegular.ttf");

        // find views and save it for later references

        textQuestion = findViewById(R.id.textQuestion);
        textScreen = findViewById(R.id.textScreen);
        textTitle = findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutParent);

        
        // set typeface of another views

        textQuestion.setTypeface(typeface);
        textScreen.setTypeface(typeface);
        textTitle.setTypeface(typeface);
        editText.setTypeface(typeface);
        
        // You should initiate linearLayoutParams here
        // it will be used later

        linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                );

        linearLayoutParams.rightMargin = 30;
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        smallbigforth = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.smallbigforth);

        keys = shuffleArray(keys);

        for (String key : keys) {
            addView(linearLayout, key);
        }

        maxPresCounter = 4;
    }


    private String[] shuffleArray(String[] ar) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            String a = ar[index];
            ar[index] = ar[i];
            ar[i] = a;
        }
        return ar;
    }


    private void addView(LinearLayout viewParent, final String text) {


        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);

        // set LayoutParams of newly created textView

        textView.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);
        textView.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bgpink));
        textView.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPurple));
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setText(text);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setFocusable(true);
        textView.setTextSize(32);

        // set typeface of newly created textView
        
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (presCounter < maxPresCounter) {
                    if (presCounter == 0)
                        editText.setText("");

                    editText.setText(editText.getText().toString() + text);
                    textView.startAnimation(smallbigforth);
                    textView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(300);
                    presCounter++;

                    if (presCounter == maxPresCounter)
                        doValidate();
                }
            }
        });


        viewParent.addView(textView);


    }


    private void doValidate() {
        presCounter = 0;

        if (editText.getText().toString().equals(textAnswer)) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent a = new Intent(GameActivity.this, BossAct.class);
            startActivity(a);

            editText.setText("");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            editText.setText("");
        }

        keys = shuffleArray(keys);
        linearLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (String key : keys) {
            addView(linearLayout, key);
        }

    }

}
```

And that' all I know. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

as the Exception states, you are invoking a method on an object which is null.
According to the line

```
at com.practechs.kubetnew28_05.GameActivity.addView(GameActivity.java:83)
```

the **textTitle** object seems to be null. But you may check all the objects
on which the method **setTypeface(typeface)** is invoked from line 81 to 85.

The problem thus seems to have nothing to do with Android Fonts, but rather just a null object. Hope this helps!

Kind regards,
403

Comment: textQuestion.setTypeface(typeface);

Comment: that is the code there

Comment: That would mean your textQuestion object has to be null.